# Discord.py using asyncio.ensure_future() to run a async function in another script without waiting for completion?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

I'm new to stack overflow, so sorry if I mess something up here. I'm trying to make a discord bot in Python. I'm currently experiencing an issue with commands. When I run a certain command it won't take any other commands until the command is fully finished. I tried to use asyncio.ensure_future such that bot will move on without waiting for my function in the second script from completing.

```
#Yes, I am importing stuff.
    @commands.command("echo")
    async def echo(self, ctx, *, input):
        future = asyncio.ensure_future(secondscript.foo(input, ctx.channel))
        #This should execute "foo" in the secondscript without waiting for it to finish.
```

```
#The second script, "secondscript.py"
import time
async def foo(input, channel):
    time.sleep(5)
    #I know I can use asyncio.sleep(), but let's say it's important I use time.sleep() instead. 
    await channel.send(input)
    #Sends input to channel after 5 seconds.
```

Comment: And your question is, what?

Comment: I want the bot to continue operation without waiting for foo to complete. In other words, I want the bot to continue listening and responding to commands but foo to do its thing in the background. As it currently stands, the entire bot waits 5 seconds for the time to elapse before it continues where as I only want foo to do that. 

I know I can use asyncio.sleep or something like that, but it's for other things similar to time.sleep that cause the bot to pause in the same way.

Comment: With asyncio there is a huge difference between time.sleep and asyncio.sleep.  The first one is a blocking call and the second one is not.  Once a task encounters time.sleep, all the other tasks (in the same thread) are blocked until the sleep expires.  With asyncio.sleep that is not the case; other tasks can run during the sleep interval.  So if you really must use time.sleep you need to use multiple threads or processes.  Clarify the question if you need more help.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Read about asyncio's loop.run_in_executor, or asyncio's to_thread function (added in 3.11 or maybe 3.10).

Comment: I tried doing

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_in_executor(None, secondscript.foo, input, ctx.channel)

earlier, but the issue is I have to make foo a synchronous function and thus can't await channel.send()

Comment: You don't have to make foo a synchronous function.  The entry point to the thread must be a sync function, but that function can create an event loop, run the coroutine foo, and return its value.